# Web-scraping issue with rvest and selector gadget

Tags: r, web-scraping, tidyverse, rvest

I'm trying to scrape the following website for MLB draft data:

https://www.baseballamerica.com/draft-history/mlb-draft-database/#/

The issue is that I can't seem to find the correct class to input into rvest::html_nodes() in order to isolate the table. Using Chrome's "Inspect" tool, I've tried each of the classes that would seemingly identify the table:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.baseballamerica.com/draft-history/mlb-draft-database/#/"

url %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes("table-container")
```

I've also tried "search-table draft-search-table", but I keep getting the same results: "{xml_nodeset (0)}". Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated!

Comment: The table is probably loaded after the page loads with javascript. rvest will only see the data from the "sources" tab, it may not see everything the "elements" tab will show. If you need to run the javascript on a page, you'll have to use a package like Rselenium.

Answer (score 2):

Content is loaded dynamically from an API call returning json. You can use httr POST request to the API for the info

```
library(httr)

headers = c('Content-Type'='application/json')
data='{"SigningBonusMin":"0","SigningBonusMax":"0","Year":"2019","Round":"1","TeamId":"0","FourYearSchoolType":"false","JuniorCollegeType":"false","HighSchoolType":"false","OtherSchoolType":"false","OverallNumber":"0","pageId":"1","paid":"false"}'
r <- content(httr::POST(url = 'https://www.baseballamerica.com/umbraco/api/draftdatabaseapi/advancedsearch', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), body = data, encode = "json"))$Results
print(r)
```